# Reversing the order of a deserialized json.net object

Tags: c#, json

I'm working with dates and times  but my json file puts the newest instance first. I'd like to be able to iterate through the array in linear order([0,1,2,3]) from oldest to newest entrie. Im using Newtonsoft to deserialize the json. How do I go about reversing the order of this?

Here is my object

```
    // Converts json file to a serialized array of locations 
    JsonObjector jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonObjector>(jsonFile);
```

Here is a small sample of the json

```
{
  "locations" : [ {
    "timestampMs" : "1482139582626",
    "latitudeE7" : 611636226,
    "longitudeE7" : -1498703826,
    "accuracy" : 23
  }, {
    "timestampMs" : "1482139560770",
    "latitudeE7" : 611636226,
    "longitudeE7" : -1498703826,
    "accuracy" : 23
  }, {
    "timestampMs" : "1482139441012",
    "latitudeE7" : 611636226,
    "longitudeE7" : -1498703826,
    "accuracy" : 23
  }, {
    "timestampMs" : "1482139355650",
    "latitudeE7" : 611636226,
    "longitudeE7" : -1498703826,
    "accuracy" : 23
  } ]
}
```

Here are my classes

```
public class JsonObjector
{
    public Location[] locations { get; set; }
}
public class Location
{
    public string timestampMs { get; set; }
    public int latitudeE7 { get; set; }
    public int longitudeE7 { get; set; }
    public int accuracy { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to sort `Location` objects in whatever order you want:

```
JsonObjector jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonObjector>(jsonFile);

foreach(var location in jObj.locations.OrderBy(l => l.timestampsMs))
   // use location
```

NOTE: Newtonsoft json deserializer do not change order of objects.

Comment: @MitchWheat No,... Don't make me search for a SO link. do it yourself and read them carefully

Comment: @MitchWheat *for* is not *foreach*

Comment: @MitchWheat `for` != `foreach`. :)

Comment: @MitchWheat enumerator obtained only once in foreach loop

Comment: But then how do I get a particular index of the location var? location[0] doesn't do it

Comment: @L.B.. nice attitude

Comment: @JoelJacoby you said in question that you want to *iterate* over locations. Why do you need index?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy maybe I misused the word iterate. I'm using gps data to create a trip log. I'd like for location to essentially be an instance of a chunk of that gps log that i can reference and compare later in the code

Comment: @MitchWheat which part is disturbing you? being wrong or my missing the *please*

Comment: @MitchWheat Why is it so hard to say *I didn't know this*

Comment: because I did.  what's your problem?

Comment: @JoelJacoby sorry I didn't get how you are going to use locations after iterating them. Why do you need indexes? Can you provide some sample please

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy so this is how I used it and it is a 502.3 bad gateway error. It seems like a timeout because my real json file has almost 300,000 records.

Comment: @JoelJacoby Read your question, How is it related with the one you asked?

Comment: @L.B I don't understand. I only ever asked one question. How do I reverse the order of  a json object

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. Thanks every body for the help!

```
JsonObjector jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonObjector>(jsonFile);

Array.Reverse(jObj.locations);
```